# Node-express application structure that serve static files in vuejs and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static

I need to create a project with node-express that will serve static files, these files will be independent HTML files that will be loaded into an iframe in a project with Vue CLI.

I will create these HTML files, since I can use both Vue and React, which will make my project more flexible.

**I have an initial structure already in operation as follows:**

**views**

```
     register_user.html - Using Vue

     load_users.html - Using React
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// make all the files in 'public' available
// https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/services'));

// https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.htmlcon
app.get("/pages/register_user", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/register_user.html");
});

app.get("/pages/load_users", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/load_users.html");
});

// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

I now need to create a folder containing scripts that will be loaded into the HTML files that are inside the views directory, and I also need to create a file called api.js.

How can I do this in the best possible way and safely?

Comment: Read https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-develop-and-build-react-app-with-nodejs-bc06fa1c18f3. Nice example how to structure your Node.js app.

Comment: This way I will have an entire project in React UI, I need simple HTML files separated by folders, these HTML files can be created using React or Vue.

Comment: React JSX element are compiled by Babel,they will render output,and that is what you want in the end.